# sorting nested documents in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a nested field in elastic search document with 2 fields:

```
blog = Nested(
    properties={
        'id': Integer(),
        'rating': Integer()
    }
)
```

An ES document has a list of blogs: blog1, blog2 etc.

I want all the documents with blob.id = x and sorted on the rating field corresponding to that blob.
Is it feasible to perform this with an elastic search query without a ranking script. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do what you need:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "blog",
      "query": {
        "term": {
          "blog.id": 123
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "blog.rating": {
        "order": "asc",
        "nested_path": "blog",
        "nested_filter": {
          "term": {
            "blog.id": 123
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```